# Getting error Class Constructor TextLabel cannot be invoked without 'new' after migration to typescript

Tags: typescript, fullcalendar

When i use the following function with eventMouseEnter prop:

```html
_eventMouseEnter = (event: EventApi): React.ReactNode => {
    screenStore.tooltipConfig = {
      type: "normal",
      children: this._getToolTipChildren(event),
      width: "auto"
    };
    return <ToolTip />;
  };

  _getToolTipChildren = (event: EventApi): React.ReactNode => {
    return <React.Fragment>
                <TextLabel key={`${event.id}_${event.start}_key1`} fontWeight={'bold'} labelText={`${event.title}`} />
                <TextLabel key={`${event.id}_${event.start}_key2}`} labelText={event.allDay ? 'All Day' : `${formatTimeStampLocal(event.start)}-${formatTimeStampLocal(event.end)}`} />
            </React.Fragment>;
  };
  
  

export class TextLabel extends React.Component<Props> {

  render() {
    const {
      dataId,
      labelText,
      fontWeight,
      fontSize,
      lineHeight,
      colour,
      styles,
      highlighted,
      required,
      overrideColor
    } = this.props;

    const labelCSS = {
      width: styles && styles.width ? styles.width : 'auto',
      minWidth: styles && styles.width ? styles.width : 'auto',
      fontWeight: fontWeight === "bold" || highlighted ? 700 : 400,
      fontSize: `${String(fontSize)}px`,
      lineHeight: `${String(lineHeight)}px`,
      color: overrideColor !== '' ? overrideColor : highlighted ? `#0094d5` : 'auto'
    };

    return <div className={`element textlabel textlabel--${String(colour)}`} data-id={dataId} style={applyStyles(styles)}>
                <div style={labelCSS}>
                    {labelText}
                    {required && <span className="textlabel__required">*</span>}
                </div>
            </div>;
  }
}
```

I get the error when I hover over the event.
TextLabel is just a component with layered divs.

Is the fullcalendar code targetting es5?
Textlabel is also defined here.

Comment: Did you also convert `TextLabel` from js to ts? Maybe add the source code of `TextLabel` as well, it might be easier to spot the problem then.

Comment: Yes, Textlabel is also a tsx file.

Comment: Can you include its source in the question then?

Comment: I've added the source here. It's just a simple component that renders a div with the text provided...

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with component's class. Cannot see anything wrong here, but this question had similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62862856/react-typeerror-class-constructor-fullpage-cannot-be-invoked-without-new

Comment: You might be right, looks like if i swap out the implementation of the function with just a regular div it doesn't throw the error... this helps i'll figure it out.

Comment: glad to have helped, good luck ;-)